# Sockets with Packets? What should I use?

Tags: java, android, sockets

So, I'm developing an Android app that communicates with server via a socket. Now, the phone will constantly be getting data from a server. The packets will not all be the same size. The first byte of the packet is the type, and then, if applicable, the next four bytes indicate the size. After that, is that many number as floats (4 bytes).

What's the best way to read these in? calling readByte(), readFloat(), readFloat(), etc. or use these Datagram things that I stumbled upon? Explain why. If you want more details to make a better suggestion, please ask.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to DataInputStream and BuferredInputStream your sockets input stream.
You don't want Datagrams because that is for UDP not sockets.

Then I would use readByte(), optionally readInt() followed by readFloat() etc.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, if you are talking about JDK datagrams, they are not sockets, they are for UTP communication, which is lighter than TCP but less reliable, and generally used for real time audio/video streaming.

I'd go with DataInputStream/DataOutputStream, and use readByte, readInt, readFloat. This will save you a lot of details about encoding complex numbers on the wire, and also add a (thin) layer of error detection.

If you have java on the other side, it should be no problem at all. If you have C/C++ on the other side, mind that it could (but shouldn't) be using little endian instead of big endian, in which case your numbers (except readByte) will appear scrambled. You can find routines for reading and little endian numbers in java quite easily, but it can cause a bit of a pain attack for the first couple of hours :)

Comment: Thanks, could you point me in a direction for endianess, since the server is written in C. Or is it just a google search away?

Comment: You could connect to the server, capture a bunch of bytes, and knowing what it should send determine if it is sending bigendian or not .. however is much much simpler to write a few lines in java, use DataInputStream, try to connect to the server, and see is if it is returning strange numbers :) .. in case google for "java little endian stream" and you'll find stuff.